# Automatic Car engine cut off while driving

Tags: automatic-transmission, stall, peugeot, glowplugs, crank-position-sensor

I got a Peugeot 407 2006 (AUTOMATIC TRANSMISSION), and it has cutoff/stalled 3 times and I am trying to figure out what's wrong.

First time engine cutoff/stall:

After applying the brakes and coming to a stop to let another car pass, and then releasing the brake, the car cutoff/stalled (I had driven about 8 miles). Turning the key (to turn the engine back on) caused the car to judder but the ignition wouldn't turn on, the car would judder as long as the key was turned, but it wouldn't ignite. After two or three attempts. We gave up. After waiting 3 mins and trying again it ignited normally. (There is NO judder while driving). Then drove about 3 miles and parked. After 4 hours I drove back home, it was a 12 mile journey and it was fine.

Second related incident?

Went to the car in the morning tried to turn the key, and it wouldn't start. Turning the key wouldn't ignite the engine (unsure if it juddered as I turned the key). After two or three attempts. We gave up waited 3 mins and then it ignited normally. (There is NO judder while driving). Then drove 3 miles. Parked and then after 9 hours roughly drove another 3 miles home.

Third time engine cutoff/stall:

Like the first time, after driving 1 mile and then it stalled/cutoff after stopping and then trying to move off. Turning the key caused the car to judder but the ignition wouldn't turn on, the car would judder as long as the key was turned, but it wouldn't ignite. After two or three attempts. We gave up waited 3 mins and then it ignited normally. (There is NO judder while driving). I parked the car, after 45 mins I drove it home, about 2-3 miles and it was fine.

What I have had from the diagnostics:

1) Glow relay supply voltage too low

2) Crankshaft position sensor open circuit

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So took it to the mechanic indeed it needed a new crankshaft position sensor, after that was fixed they also found out one of the pistons were gone.

Car is no longer driveable. There is a metal banging sound in the engine.